# PL/SQL Access to Saved Report Data

Tags: oracle-apex

Using 4.1 (latest version).

I have an Interactive Report page in my app.  Users are free to create and save public and private reports setting any filter conditions they choose.  What I need to do is loop through these reports and "process" some data based on a column value that matches the filter condition (something like an EMPLOYEE_ID).

What I would like to do is package this functionality into a PL/SQL procedure that is scheduled using DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Other than trying to reverse engineer this from the APEX views, I am stuck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if i understand correctly: what you want to do is to retrieve  data through (pl)sql as you would through using the interactive report page?

Comment: Yes.  What I really need access to is the WHERE part of the query that the IR page is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news: there is no built-in way to get the query of an interactive report.

(I hope you can program PLSQL, otherwise you've hit a dead end.)

However, i have a package which does most of the work and is indeed processing the application metadata for IRs. It can handle both column and row filters, and also columns which have an lov laid on top of them. It doesn't handle computations or aggregates. 
You'd have to take the code and adjust it somewhat though, as my goal was returning some data through json back to the browser, but you won't have to write the query-rebuilding part anymore. I'll refer you to [my blog post](http://tpetrus.blogspot.com/2012/05/interactive-report-filtering-in-apex.html) i made about my package and why i made it, so that might clear up some of the usage of it for you. You can get the zip, and you'll need the APEX_IR package. (at time of writing, it still contains a stupid oversight in that it ignores the dis/enabled state of filters)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I just started looking at your code.  Looks like you did what I was thinking I would have to do if there was not a built-in way.

Before I get too deep.  Does your code handle all of the filter operators - contains, in, > ,etc and possible values?

Comment: It should, yes. I can't promise it's a 100% faultless though because it's not (is anything? :) ). If you do find some glaring issues feel free to contact/mail me though.

Comment: I got it working.  Thank you for your help!  

Seems strange that this functionality is not needed by more people.  I really thought that there would be an API call or that the Saved Report SQL would be stored more cleanly.  What I would really like is a VIEW.  

I will accept your answer tomorrow if no one comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Yeah - my thoughts exactly. I did my share of searching around, and the only thing that came close was the post by Simon Hunt i refer to in my post. I hope that sometime we will get better access to IR queries, it is kind of a big deal.